# Non-recursive spotlight search?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search

When using the Spotlight search at the top right of a finder window, I often want the search to be non-recursive, i.e. only look at files in that specific directory, not any directories within it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution for using the graphical interface, but i've started using the following in terminal to get the desired effect:

`mdfind FOO | grep $PWD | grep -v ^$PWD/.*/.*$`

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, unfortunately it's not possible to do this.

Strangely, I also set the 'Document Container' criteria within Spotlight and it wouldn't show any results at all.

This is extremely poor behaviour, I agree. You can give Apple feedback on OS X (from which you can post feedback on Spotlight) [here](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html).

Answer (score 2):

The command-line interface to Spotlight, [mdfind](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/mdfind.1.html), has no such capability.  (There is an `-onlyin` flag but empirically it's recursive.)

Since it's extremely unlikely that the Finder would have more capability than the command-line interface, I think it's safe to say that this is not possible.  Sorry.  That does sound like it would be a very useful feature.